# How to display `.value_counts()` in interval in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to display `.value_counts()` in interval in pandas dataframe. Here's my code

```
prob['bucket'] = pd.qcut(prob['prob good'], 20)
grouped = prob.groupby('bucket', as_index = False)
kstable = pd.DataFrame()
kstable['min_prob'] = grouped.min()['prob good']
kstable['max_prob'] = grouped.max()['prob good']
kstable['counts'] =  prob['bucket'].value_counts()
```

My Output

```
min_prob    max_prob   counts
0   0.26    0.48       NaN
1   0.49    0.52       NaN
2   0.53    0.54       NaN
3   0.55    0.56       NaN
4   0.57    0.58       NaN
```

I know that I have pronblem in `kstable['counts']` syntax, but how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use named aggregation for simplify your code, for counts is used [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) to new column `counts` and is apply function for column `bucket`:

```
prob['bucket'] = pd.qcut(prob['prob good'], 20)

kstable = prob.groupby('bucket', as_index = False).agg(min_prob=('prob good','min'),
                                                       max_prob=('prob good','max'),
                                                       counts=('bucket','size'))
```

In your solution should working with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
kstable = kstable.assign(counts = prob['bucket'].value_counts())
```